# how do I run Anaconda? after delete app data folder

Tags: python, installation, anaconda, conda, delete-file

I deleted the App Data folder by mistake, how do I run Anaconda?

Anaconda itself has not been deleted, but it does not run, and when I try to install it again, it gives an error that the path is not empty. And I don't want to lose the settings and installed libraries

Comment: Something I would try would be to check where the remaining files are located, keep them on a USB key, then on the computer deleting everything related to conda and re-installing anaconda properly, and finally importing the files you previously saved to replace their newly-installed equivalents. Did you try this ?

Comment: If you are on windows and you deleted AppData you might have many more problems than just anaconda problems. Try using the recycle bin and restore the deleted files. There are ways to look for deleted files using other methods - search for "rescue deleted folder" in your favorite search engine to find out more (or seek help from an expert). You want to do as little as possible (ideally, nothing at all!) with this computer disk until your files are recovered. From now on you will also understand the importance of regular backups of your files and starting doing that too!